# PHP, MySQL login skips code section it should be executing

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have these two php scripts working side by side:

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="users"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="clients"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION["myusername"] = $myusername;
$_SESSION["mypassword"] = $mypassword; 




//set POST variables
$url = '127.0.0.1/login_success.php';
$fields = array(
                      'user'=>urlencode($myusername),

                          'password'=>urlencode($mypassword)
               );
$fields_string = '';

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);



}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

This above script registers a session for a user, and then post to the next script using cURLs,

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){

$myusername=$_POST['user']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];

//set POST variables
$url = '127.0.0.1//$_SESSION[myusername]/';
$fields = array(
                      'user'=>urlencode($myusername),

                      'password'=>urlencode($mypassword)
               );
$fields_string = '';

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);


header("location:../$_SESSION[myusername]/");

}

?>

<html>
<body>
Login Failed
</body>
</html>
```

This last script is suppose to check if $_SESSION is set. If it is set, it must run the code under if.

But what happens is that, even with the correct credentials, the last script skips the HTML section (Login Failed). Please advice me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: wow, I've read your code 3 times now, and still I have no idea what the hell you are doing and/or trying to do. this seems like a XY problem. Tell us what you are actually trying to do in these scripts here. Because it looks a little overcomplicated...

Comment: cURL does not have a session set, the users browser does. Refactor to remove the need for cURL

Comment: cant you just error_log($count) and look into your log file? And it is really a bad practice to store your password unencrypted...

Comment: or if you want to keep it this way transmit the session id to the curl target page and recreate the session there...but a refactor is much better :)

Comment: I think the cURL section makes this complicated. What I am trying to do is transfer the original login credential through 3 scripts, then with the 4th script compare $_SESSION['myusername'] with the original username from login.

Comment: what is the response you are getting while echo $result? Please comment the header(); for testing purpose

Comment: in the second script: $url seems wrong. $url may be, $url = '127.0.0.1/'.$_SESSION[myusername].'/';

Comment: @fortune, I tried using header(location:'../index') its still wont work.. buts thats not my current problem at the moment.

Comment: what should be the value of $url u r expecting at the second script? can you give me a sample url

Comment: Just to add more details: Everything works fine if i remove the cURL section and use header('location:xyz.php') to navigate between the PHP scripts. But with this method, I cant preserve the original login details, or can I?.. I dont know

Comment: value of the url from the second script should be 127.0.0.1/username/, username being the username of the user from login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I manage to get it working. I decided to remove the 2nd script above from the mechanism. here are the changes to the 1st code

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="users"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="clients"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION["myusername"] = $myusername;
$_SESSION["mypassword"] = $mypassword; 




//set POST variables
$url = '127.0.0.1/'.$myusername .'/';
$fields = array(
                      'user'=>urlencode($myusername),

                      'password'=>urlencode($mypassword)
           );
$fields_string = '';

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

I changed the "$url"  to point straight to my site from the 1st php script.

```
<?php

session_start();
if(($_SESSION['myusername']=$_POST['user'])){

}
else {header("location:../main_login.php");}
```

my site uses the above mechanism to compare a session with the details given at login page. If they are not the same, it take you back to the login page. i wanted to do this so that I can prevent session hijacking.

Thanks to everyone who help! @fortune

I don't think anyone else would ever need this, as it seems like a problem I created for myself. but for the sake of having a solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

you are fail at here: `header("location:../$_SESSION[myusername]/");` and here: `$url = '127.0.0.1//$_SESSION[myusername]/';`

replace `header("location:../$_SESSION[myusername]/");` with `header("location:../".$_SESSION['myusername']."/");`

or

```
$newvar = $_SESSION['myusername'];
header("location:../$newvar/");
```

and `$url = '127.0.0.1//$_SESSION[myusername]/';` with `$url = '127.0.0.1/'.$_SESSION['myusername'].'/';`

Because your code doesn't have ''(quote marks) for the key of $_SESSION array to get it's value and `$url = '127.0.0.1//$_SESSION[myusername]/';` has `//` (2 slashes) and also using single quote will not get variable's values but it will assign variable name with $ mark to the new variable. Use double quotes if you want to write variables within quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate your response. You are right those were many of the problems with my initial code. I have fixed all of them and got the code to work, but being very new to Stackoverflow, I am unable to post my solution until 8 hours of asking the original question has passed.